# Android Studio - Java Method Call getBytesFromFile() Fails

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio and Oracle Java 8. I am trying to get all bytes from a file and pass them to a byte array. The code below acts like it does not see `import java.io.File;`

I get the error message:

```
 cannot resolve method getBytesFromFile(java.io.File)
```

code

```
import java.io.File;

    // ...

    File path = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
            + "/zTest-Records/");

    path.mkdirs();
    try {
        recordingFile = File.createTempFile("recording", ".pcm", path); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't create pcm file", e);
    }

    // NOTE: The code below gives error message: cannot resolve method 'getBytesFromFile(java.io.File)'
    byte[] data = getBytesFromFile(recordingFile);
```

Comment: You are calling... `byte[] data = getBytesFromFile(recordingFile);` - so that method must be there in your class (or a superclass). It has nothing to do with the File object in this context.

Comment: Yeah, where is that method defined? It's not in the code you posted, so does it exist?

Comment: IoUtility.getBytesFromFile().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is not defined, perhaps you copy paste this code from somewhere.

A quick google search points to this link:

https://code.google.com/p/picturesque/source/browse/myClasses/GetBytesFromFile.java?r=1d9332c4c969b4d35847c10f7c83b04c1ccb834f

```
package myClasses;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GetBytesFromFile {

        public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

                // Get the size of the file
                long length = file.length();

                // You cannot create an array using a long type.
                // It needs to be an int type.
                // Before converting to an int type, check
                // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
                if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        // File is too large
                }

                // Create the byte array to hold the data
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

                // Read in the bytes
                int offset = 0;
                int numRead = 0;
                while (offset < bytes.length
                           && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, Math.min(bytes.length - offset, 512*1024))) >= 0) {
                        offset += numRead;
                }

                // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
                if (offset < bytes.length) {
                        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
                }

                // Close the input stream and return bytes
                is.close();
                return bytes;
        }
}
```

You probably need to add this class to your project

Comment: It looks like getBytesFromFile() is defined in Java library import java.io.File.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13218_01/wlp/compozearchive/javadoc/portlets25/com/compoze/util/IoUtility.html#getBytesFromFile(java.io.File)

Comment: With getBytesFromFile() method defined in Java library import java.io.File. I should be able to call the method in my code. Why do I get the error message?

Comment: I posted more code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511932/android-java-call-getbytesfromfile-fails